# Replace string in between two pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

I have two questions

  1.

I am trying to replace the string between two patterns

For example I want to be able to replace `some_string` in

```
(pattern1)some_string(pattern2)
```

Right now I am getting the index of the two pattern and used `substr_replace` for the task

```
$base_url = 'pattern1_some_string&pattern2'

if (preg_match('/pattern1/', $base_url, $start, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) == 1 &&
            preg_match('/&pattern2/', $base_url, $end, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){

            $start = $start[0][1];
            $end = $end[0][1];
            $starting_offset = strlen('pattern1') + 1;
            $start_index = $start + $starting_offset;
            $replacement_range = $end - $start_index - 1;
            var_dump(substr_replace($base_url, "replacement", $start_index, $replacement_range));
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

  2.

Provided there is an easier way to do 1. , can it match the first of the detected pattern

For example I want to be able to replace some_string in

```
(pattern1)some_string(pattern2)
```

,provided that (pattern1) and (pattern2) is the first encountered pattern

```
(pattern1)(pattern1)some_string(pattern2)(pattern2) -> replacing with replacement
```

would result in

```
(pattern1)replacement(pattern2)
```

Comment: A quick comment on the rational behind the downvote would be helpful in improving the quality of the question.

Comment: I got a answer for the question 1, but the 2 it a little bit tricky. Here the question1 answer : http://pastebin.com/Gsv19L85 , if you try a little bit to figure out the question's 2 answer will appear :D ahha

Comment: I don't know about the downvote, but the fact that you start with "I have two questions" probably doesn't help.  One question per question, please.

Comment: Your approach is wrong, that's all! Don't try to find something between two patterns, write a single pattern for what you need.

Comment: Provide a real string, and what you really want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

About the question **1**, the easier way to do that is with `preg_replace`:

```
$base_url = 'pattern1_some_string&pattern2';

$reg = '/^(.*?pattern1).*(&pattern2.*)$/';

$replace = "MY_STRING";

$str = preg_replace($reg, "$1" . $replace . "$2", $base_url);

echo $str; //pattern1MY_STRING&pattern2
```

[Here you have](http://ideone.com/aTfQ7Z) a working example

About the question **2** I don't understand it very well (It is not the same question 1?). If not, can you explain it more detailed?

**UPDATE:**

If you want a more dynamic process, here you have a function:

```
function getReplaced($subject, $pattern1, $pattern2, $replace){

    $reg = '/^(.*?' . preg_quote($pattern1) . ').*(' . preg_quote($pattern2) . '.*)$/';

    return preg_replace($reg, "$1" . $replace . "$2", $subject);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

u should look preg_replace_callback Function.